# Build failed with an exception. A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, tensorflow-lite

I am currently working on a Flutter application that I want to classify using a tflite model. I updated the gradle file but the result still did not change. I am open to the ideas of people who have ideas or can give advice on the subject. Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyrU3.png)

> build.gradle file of the code is below.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException()("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'tflite'
        noCompress 'lite'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.detection_of_sth"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: please try to flutter clean, flutter pub get and run again

Comment: can you edit your question with build.gradle code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GHPrakash I did edit the question with the code you request, thanks for your helping btw.

Comment: @HardikMehta I already tried these but it does not work unfortunately. Thank you btw for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the android/build.dradle**

```
    buildscript {
        ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
    
    rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
    subprojects {
        project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
        project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

**And change the app/build.gradle**

```
        def localProperties = new Properties()
        def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
        if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
            localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
                localProperties.load(reader)
            }
        }
        
        def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
        if (flutterRoot == null) {
            throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
        }
        
        def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
        if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
            flutterVersionCode = '1'
        }
        
        def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
        if (flutterVersionName == null) {
            flutterVersionName = '1.0'
        }
        
        apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
        apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
        apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
        
        android {
            compileSdkVersion 32
        
            sourceSets {
                main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
            }
        
            defaultConfig {
                // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
                applicationId "your app name"
                // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
                // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
                minSdkVersion 21
                targetSdkVersion 32
                versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
                versionName flutterVersionName
            }
        
            buildTypes {
                release {
                    // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
                    // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
                    signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
                }
            }
            aaptOptions {
                noCompress 'tflite'
                noCompress 'lite'
            }
        }
        
        flutter {
            source '../..'
        }
        
        dependencies {
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
        }
```